# Си. Как вывести переменное количество цифр после запятой?

Tags: c++, c

К примеру, я пишу программу для подсчёта некоторых функций через ряды Тейлора (рассмотрим на примере экспоненты). При этом я прошу пользователя ввести необходимую ему погрешность. Сама функция в double округляет до 6 знаков, причем всегда. Как сделать так, чтобы она выводила k число знаков после запятой?

[image: main]

[image: functions]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value

Comment: См. табличку различных спецификаторов форматного вывода здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 4):

Модификаторы минимальной ширины поля и точности можно передавать функции printf() не как константы, а как аргументы.

Для этого в качестве заполнителя используйте звездочку (*). При сканировании строки формата функция *printf()* будет каждой звездочке * из этой строки ставить в соответствие очередной аргумент, причем в том порядке, в каком расположены аргументы. Пример:

```
int main(void)
{
  int w,p;
  float work = 1234.5678;
  
  printf ("Введите ширину поля: "); scanf("%d", &w);
  printf ("Введите точность   : "); scanf("%d", &p);

  printf("%*.*f\n", w, p, work);

  return 0;
}
```